# Translated polylang strings don't appear

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I am translating our website using Polylang. Our theme is Flatbase, fully compatible with WPML so it should also work with Polylang.

I have an issue with the custom strings. They appear in the "string translation" area, and I can type in and save the translation, but the translation doesn't show on the website, the string is still in the original language.

Apparently it is not an issue with wpml-config.xml, since I can see the strings and translate them. I posted on the module community forum but got no answer.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

it does't work that way with polylang, you need to register your custom strings in function.php file of your theme. following is the link to similar question. i hope it will be helpful, other wise let me know i'll be happy to help.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82855/custom-strings-for-translation-using-polylang-plugin